# Python Azure Graph: Access Token missing or malformed

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to access some information about users on an AD network through Azure Graph API. The code looks like this:

```py
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

TENANT = 'something.onmicrosoft.com'
TENANT_ID = '...'
CLIENT_ID = '...'
SECRET = '...'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    secret=SECRET,
    tenant=TENANT,
)
client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, TENANT_ID)

client.users.list().next()
```

credentials does not fail, but i get the following error anyway:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/ifs/home/.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 121, in __next__
    self.advance_page()
  File "/ifs/home/.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/paging.py", line 107, in advance_page
    self._response = self._get_next(self.next_link)
  File "/ifs/home/.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/users_operations.py", line 158, in internal_paging
    raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Access Token missing or malformed.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed `resource` in your code. Try to use following code:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

TENANT = 'something.onmicrosoft.com'
TENANT_ID = '...'
CLIENT_ID = '...'
SECRET = '...'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    secret=SECRET,
    tenant=TENANT_ID,
    resource="https://graph.windows.net"
)
client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials, TENANT)

client.users.list().next()
```

You can also see more detials about using Azure Active Directory Graph Rbac API via Python in [this doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/doc/graphrbac.rst#azure-active-directory-graph-rbac-api).

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: This helps! Thanks.